# The php function doesnot work, the <li> cannot be presented

Tags: javascript, php, function, html-lists

I put a function into the php file, I want to use this function to produce a list of "li" inside the 'ul'. But the php function seems not work, the 'li' was not presented in the final html. Can somebody help me? Thx a lot.

```
<?php
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
 function view_side_lt() {
        global $_G, $postlist;
        $newlist = array();
        $list = '';
        if (is_array($postlist)) {
            foreach($postlist as $temp) {
                if ($temp['first'] == 1) {
                    $query = DB::query("SELECT tid, subject FROM ".DB::table('forum_thread').
                        "
                        where authorid = '".intval($temp['
                        authorid '])."'
                        and tid < > '".intval($temp['
                        tid '])."'
                        ORDER BY 'dateline'
                        DESC LIMIT ".intval(5);
                        while ($list_temp = DB::fetch($query)) {
                            $listli = '<li>
                                < a href = "forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid='.$list_temp['tid'].'"
                            title = "'.$list_temp['subject'].'
                            "target="
                            _blank ">'.cutstr($list_temp['subject'], 10, $dot = ' ...').'</a> </li>'
                        };
                        $newlist[] = '$listli'
                        return '$newlist';
                    }
                }
            }
        };
 </script>

  <ul class="clearfix">
               "{$newlist}"
 </ul>

 ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing html markup and PHP, so of course it doesn't work

Comment: If you want to output raw markup, then drop out of PHP using `?>` or echo the output

Comment: Don't you see a ton of syntax errors?

Comment: Thanks.  can you point out some?

Answer (score 0):

add some quotes and correct the `<li>` tag.

```
$listli = '<li><a href="forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid='.$list_temp['tid'].
    '" title="'.$list_temp['subject'].'" target="_blank ">'.
    cutstr($list_temp['subject'], 10, $dot = ' ...').'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Line 2, 3, etc. are all errors, just fixing this won't resolve issues. Also this variable isn't even being outputted so it would have no effect `"{$newlist}"`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you offer some help?

Comment: Thanks. So how can make it be able to output a list of 'li'? I am just a beginner.

Comment: it looks like, that you use some template mechanism. i do not know the system, you use and i suggest you to supply a working code without changes, and the changes you want to do.